# Recover lost 5th primary partition

Tags: bitlocker, partition-recovery

I recently decided to enable bitlocker on my Windows 7 computer.
Little did I know that this meant the setup wizard would chop off a 300MB piece of my C: partition and create a primary partition from that piece.
Since one can only have 4 primary partitions at a time, this meant one other partition had to go; *without warning!*

Prior to enabling bitlocker, my (legacy/non-UEFI mode) partition scheme looked like this:

- operating system (C:)
- 350MB system-reserved partition
- data partition (D:)
- LVM containing one Intel rapid-start partition (a kind of hibernation partition; the computer has a SSD)

Afterwards it looked like this:

- operating system (C:)
- 300MB NTFS partition (created by the bitlocker setup wizard)
- 350MB system reserved partition
- **free space, where D: used to be**
- LVM containing one Intel rapid-start partition (a kind of hibernation partition; the computer has a SSD)

The computer was formatted with the system reserved partition when I got it from the vendor, and since it was not delivered with an actual windows 7 setup disk - only a disk containing an image of an already installed windows 7 - I had no choice but to live with that pesky system reserved partition.

**How do I get my data partition (D:) back?**
I can think of two ways:

- Find a way to extract an image from the free space that used to be D: which I can read later; That way I can expand the LVM to cover the space of where D: was, and recreate D: inside the LVM.
- Try to get rid of the system reserved partition and recover D: as one of four primary partitions, e.g. using [this tool](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm).

How do I do either of these? Are there other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the bitlocker setup wizard is really stupid: not only did it ditch one of my partitions without asking, it also created the 300MB partition as a *new* system reserved partition, making the old one (of size 350MB) obsolete. I could just delete this obsolete partiton and recover the lost data partition using the [tool described above](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm).

If you try this and afterwards you computers complains that it cannot find an operating system, boot using your windoes 7 recovery disk/partition and opt for the windows startup repair tool that you can find on there.